# How to forward incoming traffic from MacBook to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi

I have a MacBook and a Raspberry Pi.

I have the MacBook connected to a router.

The Raspberry Pi is connected to LTE w/ a SIM card.

- I want all traffic received by the MacBook to be forwarded to the Raspberry Pi, before continuing to the internet.
- I want all traffic received by the Raspberry Pi to be forwarded to the MacBook, before continuing to the internet.

Basically, I'm trying to get them to forward traffic to each other.

I know very little about macOS. Is it possible to this? Can somebody point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

If the same thing can be accomplished more easily with a USB modem, I'm open to that option as well.

Comment: How is the Mac connected to the Pi? Does the Mac have Internet access via the router? Does the router have an Internet connection that does not go through the Pi?

Comment: I can't quite grasp what this is supposed to do. Please describe in greater detail, maybe with a concrete example (single TCP connection). What is "all traffic received"? Why would this traffic go to the internet? Why the same on both devices?